# angularjs change rootscope after promise in a controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-http, angularjs-rootscope

I'm trying to change some **$rootscope variables** from within a controller after a I have received a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) from a service.

The $rootscope variables are used to set the html page title attribute etc.

Below is the code I have, I created a function called `changeRootPageNotFound()` to change the **$rootscope variables**.  It does not work if it's called in the `promise.then` function.

```
app.controller('mainController', ['$routeParams', '$scope', '$rootScope', 'mainService', function ($routeParams, $scope, $rootScope, mainService) {
    var mainCtrl = this;
    mainCtrl.id = $routeParams.itemId;

    var promise = mainService.getData($routeParams.id);

    promise.then(function (response)
    {
        if (response.data.data) {
            mainCtrl.data = response.data.data;
        } else {
            mainCtrl.data = false;
            changeRootPageNotFound();
        }
    });
    function changeRootPageNotFound() {
        $rootScope.title = "Page Not Found - 404";
        $rootScope.titleSuffix = "";
    }
    // changeRootPageNotFound();  // works here
}]);
```

How can I change the $rootscope variables after I have received the deferred promise from the service?

Comment: Have you tried running $rootScope.$digest() after all root scope changes?

Comment: @JohnMaclein, thanks just tried it there but it didn't work

Comment: Consider putting any error message over here that you are facing.

Comment: I doupt that promise.then is launched - normal backend will throw error for invalid id and your callback wont run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `.catch` method:

```
promise.then(function (response)
{
    //if (response.data.data) {
        mainCtrl.data = response.data.data;
    //} else {
    //    mainCtrl.data = false;
    //    changeRootPageNotFound();
    //}
}).catch(function(errorResponse) {
    console.log(errorResponse.status);
    mainCtrl.data = false;
    changeRootPageNotFound();
    throw errorResponse;
});
```

The `$http` service rejects the promise when the status is outside the range 200-299.

---

> What is the `throw errorResponse;` for, can it be left out?

If the `throw errorResponse` is omitted, the rejection handler returns a value of `undefined`. This will **convert** the rejected promise to a fulfilled promise that resolves as `undefined`. If there is no further chaining, it can be left out.

A common cause of problems is programmers being unaware of this and unintentionally converting promises.

---

> instead of `.catch` you can pass the same function to then as the 2nd argument

One of the subtle differences between `.catch` and using the 2nd argument of the `.then` method, is that runtime errors in the `.then` success handler will not be caught in the rejection handler of the 2nd argument.

Comment: thanks that worked.  What is the `throw errorResponse;` for, can it be left out?  Also this seems to be the the correct way to do it, as in I don't need the `if (response.data.data)` condition

Comment: @Holy instead of `catch` you can pass the same function to then as the 2nd argument

Answer (score 1):

According to your snippet your code should have worked. In my plunker its working after the deferred promise also.

```
// Code goes here
angular.module('Test',[])
  .service('Service', function($q){
    this.ts = function(){
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      deferred.resolve("hello")
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  })
  .controller('Controller', function(Service, $rootScope){

    Service.ts().then(function(response){
      $rootScope.title="hello";
      changeRootPageNotFound();
    });

    function changeRootPageNotFound() {
        $rootScope.title = "Page Not Found - 404";
        $rootScope.titleSuffix = "";
    }
  });
```

Here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="Test">
    <div ng-controller="Controller">

      <h1>{{title}}</h1>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Please check this Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/THXDYrWuTqR8UYSJlerB?p=preview